# Modular arithmetic proof - discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It is known that an integer $a$ divides the sum and the difference of two integers $n$ and $m$, namely $a\mid(n + m)$ and $a\mid(n − m)$. Does it follow that $a$ divides $n$, if it is also known that:

1. $a$ is even
2. $a$ is odd

How do I approach/solve this? I'm at a loss with how to even begin.

Comment: Hint: If $a$ divides two numbers, $a$ also divides their sum.

Comment: If a|n+m and a|n-m then a|n+m+n-m =2m.  It's possible a has a factor in common with 2, but all other factors are in common with n.  What happens if a and 2 have no factors in common.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is even them it does not hold, e.g. assume $a=2$, $n=3$ and $m=1$. Then $a|(n+m)$ and $a|(n-m)$ but $a$ does not divide $n$ or $m$

Assume $a$ is odd, i.e. $a=2k+1$. Then $a|(n+m)$ and $a|(n-m)$ $\Rightarrow$ $a|2n$ and $a|2m$.Since $a$ cannot divide $2$ it must divide $n$.